# Custom navigation bar image and text

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I need in my app a custom navigation bar with an image and a text but I can't add the text.
Here is the code to add the image, how can I add the title?

```
let logo = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigationbaricon")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is the frame assigned for self.navigationItem.titleView? Set the frame for imageView and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the UIImageView and the UILabel (which will hold the custom title) in an UIView and then assign the UIView to the self.navigationItem.titleView. Something like this:

```
    let view = UIView(...);
    let label = UILabel(...);
    label.text = "Custom Title";

    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "..."));

    view.addSubview(image);
    view.addSubview(label);

    self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

Answer (score -2):

This one is worked for me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let titleView = UIView()
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
        titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img")!)
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        titleView.addSubview(imageView)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    }
```

[image]